# C# with SQL Server SELECT WHERE IN with data list

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with `person_id` and name fields.

In my application I have a array of `person_id`, I need to get from my database, person records with ids from my array.

Comment: What version of .net are you using? Show what you have tried so far?

Comment: What technology are you using to connect to SQL server? Raw SqlCommands, Typed DataSets, LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework?

Comment: It is "select Person_Name from tbl_Person_Info  where Person_Id in (" + PersonIdList + ")"

Comment: Which version of SQL Server and .NET are you using? SQL Server 2008 permits table-valued parameters. You could use `select Person_Name from tbl_Person_Info where Person_Id in (select * from @PersonIdList)`, then pass a DataTable containing your IDs as that parameter.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want the SQL string, this should work:

```
var sql = "select Person_Name from tbl_Person_Info where Person_Id in ("
               + string.Join( ",", PersonIdList )
               + ")";
```

Note that there is a limit (2000, I think) on the number of items allowed in the IN clause.  Also, depending on which version of .NET you're using, `string.Join` might have different argument types that don't allow a list of integers (are they integers?) to be used.  You might have to convert them to strings first before you can join them.

**EDIT**: Please be aware that if the PersonIdList items come from user input (and are strings), this is very dangerous.  I'd suggest using a newer .NET technology in any event that would allow you to handle this much more safely -- such as LINQ or EF.

Comment: Please note that if your PersonIdList came from user input, that the above may be subject to a SQL Injection attack. At the very least, make sure that your list is a list of integers, which will make this less likely.

Comment: @John - absolutely correct.  I'm assuming they are integer (or GUID) ids and not supplied from user input.

Comment: @samadhi - if they're represented as strings and supplied by the user you need to be more careful.  You might even want to add parameters for each one instead of directly constructing the string.  That's a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for every one who help me to solve my question. var sql =string.format( "select Person_Name from tbl_Person_Info where Person_Id in ('{0}')", string.join("','", PersonIdList));

Comment: NO i used Guid.NewGuid() to generate id's, so this not use any user inputs. so i hope that it is ok. because the id is hidden from the user all the time.

Comment: @Kiquenet I agree that if the list is long it's not performant. You're probably better off using a temporary table (or table-valued parameter) and doing a join or find a completely different way to go about doing this. As for SQL Injection - see the note about the assumption that the data does not come from user input. If it does come from user input, you can always concatenate parameter placeholders (`@p1`, `@p2`, ...), then add matching parameter values for them.

Answer (score 4):

Now behold the awful power of the [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)! (provided that you're using SQL Server 2008)

Essentially, this is the means to pass your array of integers, properly typed, to a stored procedure... i.e.: no string concatenation / sql injection. Mainly this all centers around creating a SQL table-type having a single integer column... then you just pass a .NET DataTable (of the same structure) to a stored procedure expecting said type.

Step #1: Create a table-type (on SQL Server) for passing a series of integers. You only need to do this once so don't go placing it in your stored procedure.

```sql
create type IntegerValues as table (IntegerValue int)
```

Step #2: Create your stored procedure (on SQL Server).

```sql
create procedure dbo.GetPersonsByID
(
 @PersonIDs IntegerValues readonly -- must be readonly
)
as begin
    
   select
    p.*
   from [YourPersonTable] as p
       join @PersonIDs as pi
       on pi.[IntegerValue] = p.[Person_ID];

end
```

Step #3: Call your stored procedure from C#

```cs
// Written from my laptop straight into the textarea... so, it's untested.
public DataTable GetPersonsByIDs(int[] personIDs)
{
    var dtResults = new DataTable();
    var dtPersonIDs = new DataTable();

    dtPersonIDs.Columns.Add("IntegerValue", typeof(int));
    
    foreach(int id in personIDs)
    {
        dtPersonIDs.Rows.Add(id);
    }
 
    using(dtPersonIDs)
    using(var cnx = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand {
        Connection = cnx,
        CommandText = "dbo.GetPersonsByIDs",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        Parameters = {
            new SqlParameter {
                ParameterName = "PersonIDs",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, // must be structured
                Value = dtPersonIDs,
            }
        }
    })
    { 
        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
            return dtResults;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error executing GetPersonsByIDs.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this works as @tvanfosson's answer and also provides sql injection security along with it ???